# Creating multiple entries with dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to build an build an eat delivery application with java spring boot. Therefore I created a new project with controllers, repositories and services for a user and address model. I could already save successfully my new created user and my new created address separately. Now I connected my User and Address with a OneToOne connection and tried to save both entries with only one post request. Unfortunately I'm pretty clueless how to save two entries with only one post request. I already tried by my own and getting the following error message:

> " Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.example.EatMe.model.Address` from Array value (token`JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)]"

I already tried to google for this problem, but I was unable to find a solution due to the lack of my missing wording to this problem.
Could maybe some one explain to me what's the correct way to do multiple transactions in one request.

I created the following user model.

```
package com.example.EatMe.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
    
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String surname;
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String mail;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String userType;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private Set<Address> addresses;
    
    public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }
    
    public void setAddresses(Set<Address> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }
    
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }
    
        public void setSurname(String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
        }
    
        public String getMail() {
            return mail;
        }
    
        public void setMail(String mail) {
            this.mail = mail;
        }
    
        public String getUserType() {
            return userType;
        }
    
        public void setUserType(String userType) {
            this.userType = userType;
        }
    
    }
```

This is my user Controller and the UserSerivce.

```
package com.example.EatMe.controller;

import com.example.EatMe.model.User;
import com.example.EatMe.service.AddressService;
import com.example.EatMe.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.\*;

@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private AddressService addressService;
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User newUser){
        return userService.addUser(newUser);
    
    }
    
    @PatchMapping("/editMail")
    public ResponseEntity<User> editMail(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id,@RequestParam(value = "mail") String mail){
        return userService.setEmail(id, mail);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteUser")
    public ResponseEntity<User> deleteUser(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id){
        return userService.deleteUser(id);
    }

}

package com.example.EatMe.service;

import com.example.EatMe.model.User;
import com.example.EatMe.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class UserService {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

    public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User newUser){
        var userInDB = userRepository.findByMail(newUser.getMail());
        if(userInDB.isPresent()){
            return new ResponseEntity("Email is already used.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }else{
            userRepository.save(newUser);
            return new ResponseEntity("New user added.", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    
    }
    
    public ResponseEntity<User> setEmail(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id,@RequestParam(value = "mail") String mail){
        Optional<User> userToEdit = userRepository.findById(id);
            if(userToEdit.isPresent()){
                userToEdit.get().setMail(mail);
                User userToSave = userRepository.save(userToEdit.get());
                return new ResponseEntity("Email was edited to " + userToSave.getMail(), HttpStatus.OK);
            }else{
                return new ResponseEntity("User not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
    }
    
    public ResponseEntity<User> deleteUser(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id){
        Optional<User> userToDelete = userRepository.findById(id);
        if(userToDelete.isPresent()){
            userRepository.deleteById(id);
            return new ResponseEntity("User deleted" , HttpStatus.OK);
        }else {
            return new ResponseEntity("User not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

}
userRepository.deleteById(id);
```

I also created the address model, controller and service

```
package com.example.EatMe.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String street;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer streetNumber;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer postcode;

    private Integer userId;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public Integer getStreetNumber() {
        return streetNumber;
    }

    public void setStreetNumber(Integer streetNumber) {
        this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
    }

    public Integer getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode(Integer postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}

package com.example.EatMe.controller;

import com.example.EatMe.model.Address;
import com.example.EatMe.service.AddressService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/address")
public class AddressController {
@Autowired
private AddressService addressService;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<Address> addUser(@RequestBody Address newAddress){
        return addressService.addAddress(newAddress);
    
    }

}


package com.example.EatMe.service;

import com.example.EatMe.model.Address;
import com.example.EatMe.repository.AddressRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

@Service
public class AddressService {

    @Autowired
    private AddressRepository addressRepository;
    
    public ResponseEntity<Address> addAddress(@RequestBody Address address){
            addressRepository.save(address);
            return new ResponseEntity("New address created.", HttpStatus.OK);
        }

}
```

Now I tried to combine the service call in my UserController to take both Requestbodies and save them at once. But like I implemented it the Address model needs the UserId which is not created at the time I'm trying to save my address

```
package com.example.EatMe.controller;

import com.example.EatMe.model.Address;
import com.example.EatMe.model.User;
import com.example.EatMe.service.AddressService;
import com.example.EatMe.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.\*;

@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private AddressService addressService;
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody Address newAddress, @RequestBody User newUser){
        addressService.addAddress(newAddress);
        return userService.addUser(newUser);
    
    }
    
    @PatchMapping("/editMail")
    public ResponseEntity<User> editMail(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id,@RequestParam(value = "mail") String mail){
        return userService.setEmail(id, mail);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteUser")
    public ResponseEntity<User> deleteUser(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id){
        return userService.deleteUser(id);
    }

}
```

The following is the request I'm sending with postman to the application

```
[{
"street": "testStreet",
"streetNumber" : 1,
"postcode" : 1234

},{
"name": "Max",
"surname":"Muster",
"mail":"test@mail.de",
"userType":"none"
}]
```

If someone needs any further information just tell me I excluded my repositories at this point due to the fact that I only implemented a findByMail method, nothing much.

Answer (score 0):

@RequestBody annotated parameter is expected to hold the entire body of the request and bind to one object.

You have to wrap this request to one object

```
{
    "address":{},
    "user":{}
}
```

You actually tried to pass an array of different objects

Comment: I changed my request to the following:
    
    {
        "user":{
        "name": "Max",
         ....
        },
        "address":{
        "street": "testStreet",
        .....
        }
    }
No Im getting the error message that my model is missing:
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.example.EatMe.model.User> com.example.EatMe.controller.UserController.addUser(com.example.EatMe.model.User,com.example.EatMe.model.Address)]

Comment: I tried to reach my newUser and print it out and changed my function to the following:
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User newUser,@RequestBody Address newAddress){
        System.out.println(newUser);

//        addressService.addAddress(newAddress);
          return userService.addUser(newUser);
        }

Comment: Read again, you should create new type which wrapping your request `public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody AddressAndUserReqest request)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @viking. I think a DTO would be that what I need to achieve my goal.